# Endogeneous binary variable with rare event problem

Tags: panel-data, dataset, binary-data, endogeneity, variable

I am working with panel data and estimating twoway fixed effect model where I am interested in the effect of treatment (binary variable). However, the assignment to treatment may be endogeneous hence I would like to treat for this. I have tried both instrumental variable approach and matching method. However since the treatment is very unbalanced (only 5% of individiuals received treatment) the logistic regression does not work very well. I have read there is a possibility of oversampling data in rare event problem. However is it possible to do it also for the purpose of treating possible endogeneity? Thank you for the help.